# How to get the last row of Google DataTable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, google-visualization

I have Temperature, Humidity and Time data and can fetch all the values from a database table for use in the DataTable. But I also want to extract the last set of values in the DataTable and print it in console.log.

I tried to print the `console.log(data)` as shown below and can see all values

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'line']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineColors);

  function drawLineColors() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
     data.addColumn('string', 'time');
     data.addColumn('number', 'Temperature');
     data.addColumn('number', 'Humidity');

      data.addRows([  

        <?php 
       if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
               echo " 
           ['".$row['time']."',".$row['temp'].",".$row['hum']."],";
           }   
       }
     ?>
          ]);
          console.log(data);

   var options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Sensors Scale'
    },
    colors: ['#a52714', '#097138']
  };

  var chart = new 

  google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: Why not just `console.log(data[data.length-1]);` ?

Comment: Instead of manually creating json data in PHP, just build an array that looks like you want and use `json_encode()` to turn it into json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `.getValue(rowIndex, columnIndex)` (see [docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable)).

This way you can also easily pick and choose what you want, e.g. you might decide you want to use only the temperature, or the humidity values for example, not just the entire row.

```
let rowIndex = data.getNumberOfRows() - 1; //gets the row index of last row
let lastTime = data.getValue(rowIndex, 0); //gets the first column
let lastTemp = data.getValue(rowIndex, 1); //gets second column
let lastHum = data.getValue(rowIndex,2); //gets third column

console.log(`[${lastTime}, ${lastTemp}, ${lastHum}]`);
```